# ¿Cómo usar repositorio local de Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Tengo un repositorio de **Maven** local y funciona pues al ejecutar en una consola `mvn --v` obtengo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora al crear un proyecto **maven** con Spring Tool Suite 4
me muestra este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede ayudarme soy nuevo en **Spring**. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se creó el proyecto o aborta la acción al dar este error?

Comment: se crea pero muetra errores en el **pom.xml** porque no puede descargar las dependencias.

Comment: Podrías adjuntar el pom de tu proyecto y contarnos un poco como lo creaste. Tambien te recomiendo que veas como preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask